# p0016 p0011 After shop replaced Crankshaft Oil Seal. Could that have caused these codes? VW CC 2010 2.0TSI CBFA

Tags: vw, oil-leak, timing, crankshaft

I took my VW CC 2010 2.0T CBFA to the mechanic shop for an oil leak. I had scanned it the day before and it had no codes.
After they replaced the Crankshaft Oil Seal I drove it home and got 2 codes that same day.

P0016 Crankshaft Position - Camshaft Position Correlation Bank 1 Sensor A

P0011 "A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Advance or System Performance Bank 1

I took it back and they claimed there's no way that replacing the seal could've caused any of those codes related to the timing but to me, this seems like too big of a coincidence.

I have driven this car for tens of thousands of miles without any timing issues.

Now the car takes longer to start up and the CEL is on.

What would you do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is to check that those sensors, that is the crank position and the cam position sensors, are properly connected.

I agree that replacing the seal should not impact these but the connectors may have been removed in order to perform that service.